# Web Page update without polling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, polling

I'm developing a web app where a user can request a service and a provider will be available to respond to him. So, When a user requests for some sort of service, our application will send a notification to the provider (asking him to respond to the user).
What I'm trying to do is: when a user requests a service, the provider gets the notification instantly (something like facebook does).

One way to get this is using AJAX to send requests to the server every 5-10 secs; what we call is polling (so far i know). But, this method has some defects, i see:-

- Since, the request will be sent every 5-10 secs, it will be a load to the server to manipulate requests and return empty data(very frequently).
- Also its useless to send requests to the server even when there are not any updates.
- Imagine someone request a service just after the server has responded to a request. So, providers must have to wait another 5-10 secs to get a notification that someone has requested something.

So, I wanted to know if there is some technique where we can update our web page instantly when a change occurs in our system without polling requests using AJAX.

Comment: Sounds like you want to look into websockets. I suggest getting started with http://socket.io. Don't fret because its node, there is a spec for the server that you can build in PHP and you can simply use the socket.io-client

Comment: As @jibsales said one option is websockets, the other option is a modified type of polling call long polling. I would look into both to see which one will be better for you.

Comment: Your other feasible alternative to websockets is Server Sent Events. EventSource is the Javascript wrapper for this API. They work in a similar way to websockets except that the data only comes **from** the server, it doesn't go back again. Of course you can do an Ajax post to send data back again... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Answer (score 4):

here is a simple Server Sent Event Script using php.

support

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

js

```
var sse=new EventSource("sse.php");
sse.onmessage=function(e){
 document.body.innerHTML=e.data;
};
```

sse.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); // specific sse mimetype
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // no cache
while(true) {
 if(/*something changes*/){
  echo "id: ".time().PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: ".$data.PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
 }
  ob_flush(); // clear memory
  flush(); // clear memory
  sleep(10);// seconds 
}
```

this keeps the connection open with the client,

then it checks if something is changed ... db/file whatever

outputs the data if changed

and then clears the php cache

waits 10 seconds and does it again.

---

As you can see the client recieves the data only if something changes on the server

but i totally don't know how the server could handle 1000's of people.

---

node.js would be a better way. but it depends what languages you are using and/or if you can actually use node.js.

websockets is both ways.

server sent event is oneway.(you need this)

**EDIT**

more data inside the sse response:

js

```
var sse=new EventSource("sse.php");
sse.onmessage=function(e){
 console.log(JSON.parse(e.data))
};
```

sse.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); // specific sse mimetype
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // no cache
while(true) {
 if(/*something changes*/){
  echo "id: ".time().PHP_EOL;

  $dataArray=array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name,'more'=>$more);
  echo "data: ".json_encode($dataArray).PHP_EOL;

  echo PHP_EOL;

 }
  ob_flush(); // clear memory
  flush(); // clear memory
  sleep(10);// seconds 
}
```

if you need some more info just ask

Comment: As you mentioned above that it waits 10 secs to repeat the process again, so do you really think Server Sent Events will be a solution? I don't know if i am asking a good question.

Comment: sse is made for what you are asking for. but php isn't made to stream data. the solition is for sure better then polling. by changing the sleep(10) to sleep(3) it repeats the process every 3 sec..

Comment: I am going to try SSE for sure and websockets as well. One more question, what if remove the sleep() function from the php script and also what if i need to send some parameters(like user id or something) when i make a call to the script?

Comment: if you remove sleep() the server crashes. 3sec is fast enough to get a  response. else change it to 1-2... the data can contain a string. so if you want to add extra data convert it to json.i add the example.

Comment: am gonna try this, vote up for you. will come up with queries soon.