# refresh PHP page using ajax and echo PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a PHP page which has a few queries on, i want to be able to include this PHP page in my index.php and echo the results with an automatic refresh (a bit like the stack overflow inbox)

how can i do this using Javascript / Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. One of solutions I could offer it's JavaScript function setInterval(); And jQuery lib to update div. For example:
javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.get('your.php',function(response){
      $('#your_element_id').html(response);
    });
  },2000);
});
```

It's just solution. Be in mind you can use this way in all ways you want.
Example to update few divs.

Answer (score 0):

Just have some container on your page and every 30 seconds use ajax to check the server for new mail, updates, errors, etc. and if there is any data, set it to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in pure javascript on how you load content with ajax from the same page

index.php

```
<?php
if($_GET['time']){ echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); }else{
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tit</title>
<script>
var result;
function ajax(a,b,c){//url,function,just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}
function handler(){
 // loading gif
 result.innerHTML='';
 result.appendChild(document.createElement('img')).src='loading.gif';
 ajax('index.php?time=yes',displayResult);
}
function displayResult(){
 //this removes the loading gif
 result.innerHTML=this.response;
}
window.onload=function(){
 result=document.getElementById('result');
 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',handler,false);
}
</script>
</head><body>
<button id="button">Get Time</button>
<div id="result"></div>
</body></html>
<?php } ?>
```

now to check every 30 seconds add this code inside the window.onload function

```
var timer=setInterval(handler,30000)
```

if you have some questions .. just ask.

a better approach would be using **SSE** (server sent events) or **websockets**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689738/2450730

Comment: this is showing the html source of the included page

Comment: yes the whole content... change result.textContent to result.innerHTML

Comment: the best way would be to load only the needed data from php and create the structure with javascript

Comment: innerHTML is also not secure.

Comment: i have a loading gif on each page, the first time the div refreshes it displays the page loading gif but then it doesnt disappear

Comment: show the code else i cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: so, my loading just has this JS Code: <script>
$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
   $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
</script>

Comment: i see no loading.gif.

Comment: <div id="overlay" class="overlay">
     <img src="http://www.domain.com/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" width="25%" style="margin-top:5%;" />
     <br />
     <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>

Comment: thats because its in the above DIV

Comment: the loading gif should be implemented in the ajax function.i update the code.

Comment: can you just stop the loading from displaying on your part of the code

Comment: you didn't posted any code and asked how to load content from the same page.i answered ... Or you add more details on your question and what you wanna achieve or try it yourself.