# PHP receiving data from TCP socket repeatedly

Tags: javascript, php, tcpsocket

The idea is to connect PHP webpage and C program via TCP socket so, that webpage waits for connection from C program and receives data as soon as connection established. The code of PHP socket connection and data receiving is below:

PHP(socketRead.php):

```
 $address = 'localhost'; 
  $port = 5001; 
  if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) < 0) {    
    echo "Socket creation error";
  }
  else {
    echo "Socket created <br/>";
  }
  if (($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)) < 0) {
    echo "Host/port connection failed";
  }
  else {
    echo "Host/port connection successful <br/>";
  }
  if (($ret = socket_listen($sock, 5)) < 0) {
    echo "Socket error";
  }
  else {
    echo "Waiting connection <br/>";
  }
 if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) < 0) {
        echo "Socket connection start error";
    } else {
        echo "Awaiting data <br/>";
    }
//Connection established, reading data
    if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 1024))) {
        echo "Read error";
    } else {
        echo "Data: ".$buf;
    }
    if (isset($sock)) {
        socket_close($ret);
        socket_close($sock);
    }
    echo "<br /> Socket closed";
```

To read data from socket dynamically I use jquery request.

Javascript(index.html):

```
        function update_content() {
            var request = $.get("socket/socketRead.php");
            request.success(function(result) {
                document.write(result);
            });
        }
        update_content();
```

Worked great until I tried to add interval to read data repeatedly.

Javascript(index.html):

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){update_content();}, 1000);
```

The first connection/receiving is still works,but then I get "Connection refused" in C program when trying to connect again. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: *"Connection refused" in C program* - as you said, it's not a PHP issue :-) PHP socket functions and C use the same system calls and I suggest to use `socket_select()` in both, PHP and C, also try setting the socket `nonblocking`

Comment: Your PHP script runs once and terminates, it is not started again until the Javascript timer elapses, and may not be started again at all if the client goes away. Really you have this the wrong way round, the C program (the persistent entity) should be listening for connections and PHP (the temporary entity) should be connecting to it. Doing it this way round is asking for all manner of trouble and is not going to be a viable solution to anything in production.

Comment: DaveRandom lol I did not even notice that.. @PaulPonomarev use [`fsockopen();`](http://php.net/fsockopen) for the php connecting to the C program

Comment: I can’t use C program as listener, because it has more things to do dynamically and webpage used only to visualize data from C program. Listening to sockets in C will stop all the program until client appears

Comment: If you use nonblocking sockets with `socket_select()` the program will not stop (*wait for client*). Also consider multi threading / forking / multi process c server

Comment: The idea of nonblocking sockets server is perfect. I have to try it too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SSE for that.

**Server Sent Events**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

*this does not answer your php question ..
but SSE it's made for what you are trying to do.*

js

```
var sse=new EventSource("sse.php");
sse.onmessage=function(e){
 console.log(e.data)
};
```

sse.php

```
function send($data){
 echo "id: ".time().PHP_EOL;
 echo "data: ".$data.PHP_EOL;
 echo PHP_EOL;
 ob_flush(); // clear memory
 flush();
}

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); // specific sse mimetype
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // no cache
$address='localhost';$port=5001;

while(true){
$msg=($sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP))?'created':'error';
send("Socket creation ".$msg);

$msg=($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port))?'connected':'refused';
send("connection ".$msg);

//.... 
// do the rest  
//.....

sleep(10);
}
```

note1:Not sure if the php syntax is correct but it's just here to give you an idea.

Another example of sse .. 2nd part is also using json.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20689738/2450730

Comment: Thanks, SSE is really that what I was searching for