# Two way continuous socket communication

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, jquery, server-sent-events

I’m trying to write continuous communication between C program and webpage using sockets. I already got advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975314/php-receiving-data-from-tcp-socket-repeatedly/20975718#20975718) to use SSE on webpage. But SSE is a one-way communication. So I have tried to post data via jquery.post

Javascript(index.html):

```
        function update_content() {
            var sse = new EventSource("socket/SSE.php");
            sse.onmessage = function(e) {
                $.post("socket/SSE.php", {text: "Hello World!"});
                console.log(e.data);
            };
        }

        update_content();
```

PHP(SSE.php):

```
<?php
function send($data){
 echo "id: ".time().PHP_EOL;
 echo "data: ".$data.PHP_EOL;
 echo PHP_EOL;
 ob_flush(); // clear memory
 flush();
}

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream'); // specific sse mimetype
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // no cache
$address='localhost';$port=5001;

while(true){
$msg=($sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP))?'created':'error';
//send("Socket creation: ".$msg);

$msg=($ret = socket_connect($sock, $address, $port))?'connected':'refused';
//send("connection: ".$msg);

$text = $_POST["text"];
send("Trying to write $text");
$msg = (false === socket_write($sock, $text, strlen($text)))?"Error":"Success";
//send($msg);
$msg = (false === ($buf = socket_read($sock, 1024)))?'Error':'Success!';
send($buf);
sleep(2);
}
```

and, of course, it didn’t work because webpage only has $_POST data when called by $.post function. I see only one solution to send parameters to SSE.php(and further to C program) - browser storages. Is there any other way?

Thanks, Paul

Comment: I tried to use SessionStorage, so i added `$.post("socket/SSE.php", {text: counter});` to index.html and `if(isset($_POST["text"])){send("Value posted"); $_SESSION["text"] = $_POST["text"];}
if(isset($_SESSION["text"])){send("Session started"); $text = $_SESSION["text"];}`. But now SSE is writing one value all the time, though "counter" is incremented variable

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `SSE(Server-Sent Event)` is one-way communication ( http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp. But you can use `WebSocket API` for sending and receiving data ( see `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket ).

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but not in my case, because my data transfer is between webpage and C program(which has no websocket support) on external linux board, so I’m not sure if I can use something like [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets)

Comment: @PaulPonomarev how are C program & server interact?

Comment: As you can see here, via TCP socket. C program is a nonblocking server, who waits for connections and on connection he receives message and sends an answer